# Generate UUID as Id on object creation instead with @GeneratedValue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I have to following problem: So far I've created entities who looked more or less like this:

```
public class ExampleEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
  private UUID id;

  // Other properties...

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    ExampleEntity that = (ExampleEntity) o;
    return id.equals(that.id);
  }
}
```

This worked fine until I recently had to compare objects before they were persisted to the database. I realized that the annotation `@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")` generates the UUID not on object creation (duhh...) and all ids are `null` if the object is not represented in the database.

I am now looking for the best way to initialize my entities with a UUID as Id. Is this sufficient or is there a better way to do this?

```
public class ExampleEntity {
  @Id
  private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

  // Same as above...
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a natural key on the entity? You could use that instead for equality check. For example, if the entity is a product and there is a SKU field which is unique in your table, you can use it for business equality check. I would make this natural key required in the entity constructor. However, you would still need to persist (and `flush()`) your entity in order to fill the `@Id` which can be used for `.equals()`

Comment: No, there is no natural key. All primary keys are UUIDs.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, because there is no guarantee, that `UUID.randomUUID()` will generate unique values. You would have to call the database (there is a chance you would have to do this multiple times) to see if there is no conflict.

I'm not sure, why is `@ID` generation in the database wrong? If you want to get the id of newly created object, simply call:

```
exampleEntityRepository.save(new ExampleEntity()).getId();
```

Comment: According to the official standard (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122) UUIDs "can guarantee uniqueness across space and time" so using UUID.randomUUID() shouldn't be a problem in this scenario or am I wrong? Does   `@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")` check if the UUID already exists in the table before every insert? Yes `.save(new ExampleEntity()).getId();` works and it looks like this is what I am going to do. My initial goal was to create all the objects first and then store them in batches for performance reasons.

Comment: You're mixing some standard with the implementation. How can java know, that the `UUID` was already created, deleted and so on? What if you change it in a database? Just take a look at the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()